# MyBatis mapping result to List<String> in MyBatisRepository and annotations

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a select "Select * FROM HZ...." and it returns just one column (String)

```
NAME
name1
name2
name3
....
```

I need to map this result to a List

I've tried using a `Model` class with a String properties like next:

```
public interface ModelReport {
   String getAll = "Selct * FROM HZ....";

   @Select(getAll)
   @Results(value = {
        @Result(property = "NAME", column = "NAME"),
   })
   List<Model>getAll();
}


class Model{
  String NAME;
}
```

But I do not want create model without a class just with a List of Strings. How can I do it?

I've tried the next, but it doesn't work.

```
@Select(getAll)
List<String> getAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `ResultType` adding the annotation `@ResultType` and the value type you expect (`java.lang.String`).

```
@Select(getAll)
@ResultType("java.lang.String")
List<String> getAll();
```

Comment: where placed @ResultType annotation? in myBatis lib it not exist

Comment: org.apache.ibatis.annotations, the same as `@Result`. http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/annotations/ResultType.html